# Fields: how to avoid field-end-position to overlap with next field?

Tags: text-properties, motion

I have a text in the beginning of buffer

```
901 fifth avenue
```

The word `901` is defined as field "house" and  `fifth` (including space) as field "street".  So the text with fields is

```
123456789         <- buffer position
901 fifth avenue  <- text
hhhssssss         <- fields
```

where *h* means "house" and *s* means "street". I can confirm with `C-u C-x =` that `1` is property field equal to "house" and the following space is of field "street".  Note that `1` (part of house number) is on position 3 and   (the following space) on position 4. So far so good.  I'd like to get field locations in the form "house 1 3", "street 4 9" and so on.  So I naively assumed that I can just jump to the end of one field using `field-end` and find the next field right there.

However, when I ask `(field-end 3)` it replies 4, while `(field-beginning 4)` is 1 and `(field-end 4)` is still 4.  So at position 4 lisp thinks we are still at the first field "house" while `C-u C-x =` at position 4 tells we are at the next field "street".  First when I move to position 5 will lisp give beginning 4 and end 10 correspondingly. Why is the field-end position inside of the following field?  Note that it is *inside*, not just one-past-the-end as `(field-beginning 4)` clearly refers to the previous field.  So it seems like I have to move past the beginning of the field before lisp sees it, and then add some logic to move back, avoid jumping over the beginning of buffer, not miss length-1 fields and maybe more.

Are there any easier/more robust ways to do this?  Am I totally misunderstanding something?

The only somewhat related reference in documentation was related to stickiness but that is only relevant when inserting new characters?  *escape-from-edge* argument seems not to be answer as my problem is with the very definition of end-of-field.

GNU Emacs 26.3

Comment: Given the number of views and lack of an answer, combined with my shared bafflement after RTFM, I think you'd be justified to submit a bug report. Include a minimal reproducible example. At the very least, if it turns out that you are doing something wrong, then (I'm guessing) the documentation should be improved.